# Descale predicted values

Tags: r

Ali is a matrix with 4 target variable and 16 predictor variables. I normalized all variables then I used pcaNNet to obtain the network predicts. now how I can descaling the predicted values to original scale? thanks

```
library(clusterSim)#doing standardization
library(caret)
normAli = data.Normalization(Ali,type="n4")
# or this code : normAli = apply(Ali, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(Ali) (Ali - min(Ali))/diff(range(Ali)))

normxmat<- normAli[2:16] # predictor 
normymat<- normAli[17:20] # targets

fit<- pcaNNet(normxmat,normymat, size =10 , linout = TRUE, trace = TRUE)


pred<- predict(fit)
```

Comment: `res*diff(range(Ali))+min(Ali)`? That's not really a coding question, though, ... more algebra.

Comment: I dont understand what is your mean Frank about this code: res*diff(range(Ali))+min(Ali) , this not descaled my predicts.

Comment: It is the inverse of the transformation you applied `(Ali - min(Ali))/diff(range(Ali))`, unless I made an error. You may have to save ranges and mins for each row or column or whatever you're normalizing here.